# .Net Core 3.1 app fails to start as a windows service manual start gives 1053 error

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

We have 3.1 app we try to run as a windows serivce. In debug mode everything works fine, when we deploy and try to start de app from Services list, it gives a 1053 error

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseWindowsService()
  ...
             .ConfigureServices(
                (hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")
                        .GetValue<string>("XXXDb");

                    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
                        options =>
                        {
                            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                        }
                    );

                    services.AddHostedService<OnbekendeBurgerRegistratieProcessor>();
                    
                    services.ConfigureAppServices();
                });
        
}
```

This is our start up code.
Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Our deploy guru used some different settings in our TFS/Octopus deploy pipeline and now the problem is gone. However I do not have an answer as to why we had the problem in the first place, sorry